# How to optimize the building of a graph?

Tags: graph, hashtable

I am working on a problem where I want to travel through a graph. However I can see when I profilate my code that the building of the graph is the heavy part.
Every node should have a value with fixed length M. The graph should contain all combinations of base 2. Thus for example for M = 3, we have: "000" "001" "010" "011" "100" "101" "110" "111", i.e. 2^M = 8 combinations.

I then want to link the nodes together in a very specific way. Every node has two outoing edges, with value "0" and "1". For example "000" will be connected to "001" with edge 1 since if I delete the first number to the right and add the edges value at the end I will end up with "001". Similarily "111" is connedted to "110" by the edge "0".

Help needed. Note that the nodes does not necessary have to be represented with String but this was how I implemented but it seems to run too slow. The important things here is that the nodes are connected correctly.

I have solved this by storing the nodes in a HashTable and then looping through the whole set to connect the nodes to eachother.

Suggestions appreciated how to make this smarter.

Comment: When are two nodes connected ? I don't understand your explanations. Please give more examples and explain more thoroughly.

Comment: I suspect "101" and "000" are not connected since it takes 2 changes in "101" to reach "000". Am I right ?

Comment: Well yes, just add a number 0 or 1 at the end of the vertex number and delete the first number. Thus 111 has an egde 1 to itself. Furthermore 111 is also connected to 110 via 0. More examples, 101 is connected to 011 via an edge with value 1. It is also connected to 010 via 0. Hope these example explains the problem better.

Comment: Thanks, I'll correct my implementation

Comment: Hah, looks like a complete binary tree ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

So you basically want to take a number and derive two numbers from it

- shift it one bit to the left and unset the first bit, and let the last bit be zero
- the same as above but set the last bit to be one

Now this number is connected to these 2 numbers described above.

That is my understanding.

Here is some code I wrote to compute such a graph:

```
import pygraphviz as pgv


# length of binary codes

for n in range(3,8):
  def b(x):
    return str(bin(x))[2:].zfill(n)
  G=pgv.AGraph(directed=True)

  for i in range(1,2**n):
    for j in range(1,2**n):
      I  = b(i)
      J  = b(j)
      # we make room for another bit (the zero bit)
      i1 = i << 1
      # we unset the first bit
      i1 = i1 & ~(1<<(n+1))

      # we copy the previous result
      i2 = i1
      # we set the last bit
      i2 = i2 | 1
      if    i1 == j :
        G.add_edge(I,J,label="0")
      elif  i2 == j:
        G.add_edge(I,J,label="1")

  G.layout(prog='dot')
  G.draw("graph"+str(n)+".png")
```

n=3

[image]

n=4

[image]

n=5

[image]

n=6

[image]

P.S. Initially I tried using networkx, but soon realized pygraphviz was much easier to use for this.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your vertexes are actually numbers, why don't you use adjacency matrix where column and row numbers represent the vertexes?

Comment: you are perfectly right. The actual relation between the values is one that can be expressed through bitwise operations and counting bits.